# Itemize and overlay

Tags: itemize, overlays

I've two levels of "itemize". Every second level of itemize is related to a first level. I would like the second level to fold when I pass from a first level bullet point to another. In the following MWE, the blank spaces between the first level points stay while i would like them to desapear. I think that the MWE is clearer than my explanation...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{overprint}
\begin{block}{Pets}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<2-> Cats
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<3> Lazy
        \item<3> Cuddly
    \end{itemize}
    \item<4-> Goldfish
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<5> Wet
        \item<5> Lives in pond
    \end{itemize}
    \item<6-> Birds
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<7> Fly 
        \item<7> Have feathers
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}   
\end{block}
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Pets}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{6cm}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<2-> \strut Cats
    \only<3>{\begin{itemize}
        \item \strut Lazy
        \item \strut Cuddly
    \end{itemize}}
    \item<4-> \strut Goldfish
    \only<5>{\begin{itemize}
        \item<5> \strut Wet
        \item<5> \strut Lives in pond
    \end{itemize}}
    \item<6-> \strut Birds
    \only<7>{\begin{itemize}
        \item<7> \strut Fly 
        \item<7> \strut Have feathers
    \end{itemize}}
\end{itemize}
\end{overlayarea}   
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An animation of the result:

[image]

I added `\strut`s to minimize the "jumping" effect.